# How to get the number of installation for TFS feed package

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I need to know how many times the feed packages have been installed in our TFS

we had in our TFS server package nuget packages 
and one of our KPIs to know how many times these nugets have been downloaded or installed and get the users who installed it in their projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have this kind of audit log for azure devops server 2019.

There is no built-in logging in Team Foundation Server to fetch the times of feed packaged download or installed.

TFS does internally keep a (temporary) log of some actions through the Command (`tbl_Command`) table in the TFS databases, which is also accessible through the Activity Log page:

```
http://server:port/tfs/_oi
```

And this data is only kept for 14 days by default. Some background details on the Operational Insights page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2013/03/30/how-to-see-activity-and-job-history-in-tfs-2012/

Unfortunately,after go through and double check, there is not related information stored  of what you are looking for.